# Adding Text to Cells with Text - Apps Script

Tags: arrays, string, google-apps-script, data-manipulation

Simple enough, I want to add "navigatela.lacity.org/" to the beginning of each cell in column G programmatically (bar the header).
What different ways could I go about doing this?

Thank you! Your help is greatly appreciated :D

[image]

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Also, you want to replace the information that is currently in the cell in the G column with:
`navigatela.lacity.org/ + current cell`

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to add a text of `navigatela.lacity.org/` to the top of the value in the column "G".
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const add = "navigatela.lacity.org/"; // This is from your question.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set your sheet name.
  sheet.getRange("G2:G" + sheet.getLastRow()).createTextFinder("(^.*$)").useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(`${add}$1`);
}
```

- When this script is run, the text of `navigatela.lacity.org/` is added to the top of the value in the column "G". In this case, this text is not added to the empty cells.

#### References:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#createTextFinder(String))
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function addToBeginning() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Enter Your Sheet Name");
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 7, sh.getLastrow() - 1).getValues().flat();
  let oA = vs.map(e => `navigatela.lacity.org/${e}`);
  sh.getRange(2, 7, oA.length, oA[0].length).setValues(oA);
}
```